# Continuity of functions of 2 variables

Tags: real-analysis

What is the general approach to check the continuity of functions of two variables . For example : considering function : $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x+y}.$  Is this function continuous at origin .. ?  Along the path $y = -x$ , denominator tends to zero, by intuition I feel it's not continuous .. As function should be continuous through every path at that point. Thank you

Comment: Along the path $y=- x$ the denominator *is* zero.

Answer (score 0):

First for a function to be continuous at a point it must be defined at that point so let’s check that $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}$ is defined at the origin.

In some sense it is division by zero and so not defined but in another sense one usually tries to define a function at such points by taking the limit. So let’s try to take the limit to the origin.

First we observe that your function is definitely not defined elsewhere on the line $y=-x$ as $\frac z\epsilon\to\pm\infty$ as $\epsilon\to0,$ so long as $z\not\to0.$ This we only check limits from regions where the function is defined.

Consider taking points at $x=r\cos\theta,\;y=r\sin\theta.$ then we can rewrite the function as $\frac{r^2}{r(\cos\theta +\sin\theta)}$ which we may simplify to $\frac{r}{\cos\theta +\sin\theta}$ and so conclude that the limit does exist at the origin and is 0.

Now the function must be continuous at 0 by construction. Recall that a function is continuous at a point if and only if the limit exists at that point and agrees with the value of the function at that point. The function is continuous everywhere else it is defined as the denominator is nonzero and all the operations in its definition are continuous.

To conclude:
The function defined by
$$f(x,y) =\frac{x^2+y^2}{x+y}$$
is not defined as a function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ but is defined and continuous everywhere as a function $f : X\to\mathbb R$ where $X=\mathbb R^2 - \{\lambda (1,-1)\, |\, \lambda \ne 0 \}.$

Comment: Similarly if we consider function ${|x|^y}$ , By substituting $x=r\cos\theta,\;y=r\sin\theta.$ then we can rewrite the function as ${r\cos\theta}^ {r\sin\theta}$ . For ${\theta<0}$,function will not be continuous right ??

Comment: No. $|x|^y$ is continuous everywhere except at the origin where it is undefined because $0^0$ is not defined. It cannot be defined in a way that makes the function continuous because the limit at 0 does not exist. Indeed if you take the limit along the path $y=0$ the limit is 1 but along the path $x^0$ the limit is 0.